# How can I get the ForeignKey field instead of the related object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this:

```
Class A(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Class B(models.Model):
     a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
     a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

When i need the attribute `a` in an object of `C`:

```
related_manager = getattr(object_c,'a')
```

and this give me a `ManyRelatedManager` but the problem is when i need the attribute `a` in a object of `B`:

```
object_b2 = getattr(object_b,'a')
```

this give me a object of class B and i need know if is a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField, i mean, i need getattr(something, 'some_attribute') and get the models.* not the object in self.

Comment: Are you really getting a object of class B if you to `getattr(object_c, 'a')` ? I expected to get an object of Class **A**.

Comment: Yes, that does happen. Give it a try. getattr on a ManyToMany gives you the manager, just like if you called object.my_many_to_many_field... you'd still have to call .get() or .all() to get an object from it.

Comment: @Felix, it's not an object of class B, it's the manager: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x8cee6cc>. getattr is working the same as object_c.a and object_b.a.

Comment: @Dingle: Sorry, it was a typo, I meant: `getattr(object_b, 'a')`. The OP wrote he gets an object of class B but I think he gets an object of class A. Anyway, as this question is answered this doesn't matter anymore ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into this before with getattr. Model introspection is the solution.

If you know the field name, the best way to do it is to use a method in the object's `_meta` section (*ooooh, scary!*).

```
object_b2._meta.get_field_by_name('a')[0]
```

That [0] at the end is because the method actually returns lots of other useful and interesting information in a tuple. But if you just want the field itself, that's the way to do it.

Without giving code, the way to do it if you don't know the name of the field is to iterate of `_meta.fields` and find the one where `field.rel.to` is the model you're looking for.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

A `ForeignKey` only leads to a single model. If you need to get a manager when accessing the attribute then use `ManyToMany` with [an intermediary table](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) that has a `ForeignKey` with `unique` enabled.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. His problem is that getattr on a foreignkey queries the related model and returns an object, whereas getattr on a manytomany returns an object manager.